# Flatten Nested XML for SQL View

Tags: sql-server, xml, nested, view

**Summary:**

Given a SQL Server db table that contains columns of various types, one being an XML column, I need to digest the XML for each row and present this data in a view.

**Assume the following table for simplicity:**

Table name: Study

Columns:

1. StudyId (PK, int, not null)
2. Name (nvarchar, not null)
3. Objects (XML, null)

**Assume the following values for 1 row:**

1. 123
2. "A Study"
3. See below, StackOverflow wouldn't let me use code insertion, so here it is as html...

```html
<objects>
  <Group Name="Group1">
    <Treatment Drug="Grp1DrugA" />
    <Treatment Drug="Grp1DrugB" />
  </Group>
  <Group Name="Group2">
    <Treatment Drug="Grp2DrugC" />
  </Group>
</objects>
```

**Desired Output:**

[image: Desired Output]

**Note:**

Here are a couple of the numerous approaches I've tried for this, I can list more if that would be helpful.

Most posts I've read on these sort of operations involve a declared xml variable. My understanding is that you cannot create/use variables inside a view, so I'm a bit stuck.

**Approach 1:**

```
select  stud.StudyId,
    stud.Name as 'StudyName',
    tbl.treatment.value('(../Group/@Name)[1]','varchar(30)') as 'Group',
    tbl.treatment.value('(@Drug)[1]', 'varchar(30)') as 'Drug' 

from dbo.Study stud
cross apply stud.StudyObjects.nodes('//Group/Treatment') as tbl(treatment)
```

This gives me nothing in my Group column.

**Approach 2:**

```
select  stud.StudyId,
    stud.Name as 'StudyName',
    grp.value('(@Name)[1]', 'varchar(30)') as 'Group',
    treatment.value('(@Drug)[1]', 'varchar(30)') as 'Drug'

from    dbo.Study stud
    cross apply stud.StudyObjects.nodes('//Group') as table1(grp)
    cross apply grp.nodes('//Group/Treatment') as table2(treatment)
```

This results in every combination of groups/treatments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this way

```
SELECT
        StudyId
        ,Name
        ,o.value('../@Name', 'varchar(30)') [Group]
        ,o.value('@Drug', 'varchar(30)') Drug
    FROM Study S
        CROSS APPLY S.[Objects].nodes('objects/Group/Treatment') xmlData(o)
```

Got this result

```
StudyId     Name       Group        Drug
----------- ---------- ------------ ------------
123         A Study    Group1       Grp1DrugA
123         A Study    Group1       Grp1DrugB
123         A Study    Group2       Grp2DrugC
```

Hope it helps.